# Предупреждение "Variable might not have been initialized'

Tags: delphi

> k1,k2,n1,n2: Variable <Имя> might not have been initialized

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a:array[1..2,1..4] of char; i,j,k1,k2,n1,n2:integer;
max,min:char;
begin
  for i:= 1 to 2 do
  for j:= 1 to 4 do
    a[i,j]:=stringgrid1.cells[i-1,j-1][1];
  max:=a[1,1];
  for i:= 1 to 2 do
    for j:= 1 to 4 do
      if a[i,j]>max then 
        begin 
          max:=a[i,j]; k1:=i; k2:=j end;
          min:=a[1,1];
          for i:=1 to 2 do
            for j:=1 to 4 do
              if a[i,j]<min then 
                begin
                  min:=a[i,j]; n1:=i; n2:=j end;
                  a[k1,k2]:=min;
                  a[n1,n2]:=max;
                  for i:= 1 to 2 do
                    for j:= 1 to 4 do
                      stringgrid1.Cells[i-1,j-1]:=a[i,j];
                end;    
         end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда у вас есть условная конструкция:

```
if a[i,j]>max then begin max:=a[i,j]; k1:=i; k2:=j end;
```

Вас компилятор предупредит о том, что перед использованием переменных стоило бы их определить во всех областях. А у вас они определены только при каком-то условии.

Comment: >Вас компилятор предупредит о том, что перед использованием переменных стоило бы >их определить во всех областях. А у вас они определены только при каком-то >условии. Условия для этого и нужны, чтобы определить переменных только в тех областях, в которых нужно, а не во всех

Answer (score 0):

Переводом фразы "Variable <Имя> might not have been initialized" является фраза "Переменная <Имя>, возможно, не была инициализирована". Например, значение k1 присваивается в блоке if и при определенных значениях в условном выражении условный оператор не будет выполнен, как следствие, ниже по коду при обращении к массиву a по индексу k1 возможна ошибка.